# storage limit of maximo anywhere application in offline mode

Tags: maximo-anywhere

I would like to know if Maximo anywhere application is running in offline mode then how much data it can save? The scenario is that, engineer visit remote plants for around weeks (Oil & Gas plants) and they will be using anywhere app in disconnected mode and do 100s of transactions. Will anywhere application store so many records in offline mode inside the device or it will crash? Or is there any way to configure this size limit.

Appreciate any help in this regards.

Comment: There's no configuration option to limit the offline transaction data. We use a sqllite database on the device filesystem to store the local data in JSON format (provided by MobileFirst/Worklight).  The transaction size is actually pretty small, you shouldn't see too much growth.  You  can predict the growth you might see by downloading all lookup data and the current work list, taking the device offline, checking the App information panel in the Application Settings in Android to see the local data size.  Then use the application for a day and remeasure.

Answer (score 0):

Usually we download about 100MB of data to the device from the Maximo server.  The large majority of the data is lookup related (assets, failure codes, locations), not work list or transactional related data.